# Symbolic summation of series in R?

Tags: r, symbolic-math

Is there a (matlab) [symsum](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/symbolic/f1-82523.html#f1-103680) equivalent in R?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R doesn't do symbolic maths by itself but you can link to yacas, which does (via the `Ryacas` package).